# Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

While creating query in postgres, I resulting an error

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

and this is my query

```
SELECT 
        u.*, 
        m.*,
        g.group_name as group_name, 
        g.id as group_id, 
        c.city, 
        m.city as id_city, 
        c.id_province, 
        p.province 
    FROM 
        ref_user u 
        JOIN ref_mitra m 
        JOIN ref_usergroup g 
        JOIN ref_city c 
        JOIN ref_province p 
        ON 
        u.id_mitra = m.id_mitra 
        AND g.id = m.company_group 
        AND c.id_city = m.city 
        AND c.id_province = p.id_province 
    WHERE 
        u.active = 'N' AND u.uid= 'testing@gmail.com'
```

In MySQL that sql works,
but now I use postgreSQL and it is not working.

What's wrong?

Comment: Those incomplete JOIN conditions are **completely** invalid SQL. Does MySQL _really_ accept that? That's insane

Comment: In mysql a join without a condition is treated as a cross join which is why the ref_province on clause is needing to filter all those other tables as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use the keyword "on" on every keyword join:

```
SELECT u.*, 
       m.*,
       g.group_name as group_name, 
       g.id as group_id, 
       c.city, 
       m.city as id_city, 
       c.id_province, 
       p.province 
FROM 
       ref_user u 
       JOIN ref_mitra m on u.id_mitra = m.id_mitra 
       JOIN ref_usergroup g on g.id = m.company_group 
       JOIN ref_city c on c.id_city = m.city 
       JOIN ref_province p on c.id_province = p.id_province 
WHERE 
       u.active = 'N' AND u.uid= 'testing@gmail.com'
```